# colon operator ":" gets sent as "="

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, get

Trying to learn of the get() request in jQuery, the colon operator ":" gets sent as "=". Can anyone explain? Request sent http://192.168.1.1/?pin=111

I am a newbie to stackoverflow and java, kindly bear with me if the question is too basic

```
$(".button").click(function () {                  
            var p = $(this).attr('id');           
            pin:p                       
            $.get("http://192.168.1.1:80/", { pin:p });
});
```

Comment: Because jQuery is turming your object into url get parameters, ie `dataName=value`, so the data can be sent.

Comment: Is the pin:p an object or the 'p' alone?

Comment: The bare `pin:p` is nothing; it's a label w/ a no-op variable reference. `{ pin: p }` is an object with a key of `"pin"` and the value `p`.

Comment: an object of what class? I mean class related to HTML or jQuery

Comment: @neths — Object. Neither HTML nor jQuery. It's core JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ pin:p }` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for jQuery says that the data will be encoded:

> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to false. For example, `{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }` is converted to the string `"a=bc&d=e%2Cf"`.

This is the standard encoding for [a query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).